# How to initialize JavaScript on dynamically loaded elements?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using a HTML 5 media player https://github.com/Selz/plyr
It can be initialized on a page by using:

```
plyr.setup();
```

But if an element (`<video>` in this case) is loaded dynamically, it has to be initialized again. But can't find out how do do this?
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: re-run `plyr.setup();` ?

Comment: @n00dl3, yes I know but because i am not a programmer, don't know how to do that?

Comment: Stack overflow is full of programmer but there's no medium here, if you want some help, you need to provide some code. Nobody can guess how your application works.

Comment: check if case is `<video>` then initialize after video otherwise on load of page

Comment: @binary10 to re-run `plyr.setup();`, have a line of code that says: `plyr.setup();`

Answer (score 0):

In your function where you are creating the element, set an id for the dynamic element and add this:

```
plyr.setup(document.querySelector('#{your_dynamic_content_id}'), options);
```